# How to find out where current location is requested

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have an iOS app that uses Core Location to get the user's location, which pops up the request for permission on the first attempts. However, there are moments where the user will not be able to operate the screen, so at these times I don't want to ask for a location. I check before each call to `CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation`, and set map views to not show the user location. The problem is that there is still something trying to access the use location, as the permissions popup is still shown, and I am unable to find where this happens.

So, what other actions could trigger this? And, probably most useful: is there a way I can set a symbolic breakpoint on something that fires always whenever access to the current location is requested? I tried setting one on `[UIAlertView show]`, but that doesn't fire, presumably because the alert is shown by the system, rather than my app?

Comment: your code is only one, nothing else triggers it.

Comment: Do you use other location methods like: `startUpdatingHeading`, `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, `startMonitoringForRegion`, `startRangingBeaconsInRegion` - They would also bring up the dialog.

Comment: @holex: it may be a library or framework I am using. @William: I do use `startUpdatingHeading` as well, but I also check before calling that, and put a breakpoint to check it is indeed not being called

Comment: @sgvd, if you are using a 3rd party framework, you should check that framework's documantation first... no one can give you precise answer, because in general _your code_ triggers it, even if you don't know what _your code_ does in runtime. you can give us more information about _your code_ anytime in your post.

Comment: @holex: I am indeed pretty sure that my code triggers it somewhere, I certainly hope I don't have code being called out of the blue.. The problem is that I have checked, as far as I can tell, all calls I make directly to Core Location. I would like to tell you about the part of my code that is relevant, but that's the point: I am not able to find which code that is (yes I did my best looking and yes I do read documentation), and am looking for a general way of finding it.